# HTML2PS pdf using cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3, html2ps

The pdf file thas generated from class is not opened. I have get the message when I try to open pdf: 
"Adobe reader could open "test.pdf" because it is either not a support file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as email attachment and was'nt correctly decoded).

hope you will find solution for me!

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The information you're giving is not where near enough for anyone to solve your problem.
What I do get is that you have a problem with the ps/pdf generation, but what and where we cannot guess! So no we cannot find a solution for you since we do not know what your problem could be... Read this [page on How To Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Also why are you using this library - `html2ps/html2pdf` ? It is ancient already.
I could propose some other solutions that are contemporary:

[DomPdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)
[Mpdf](http://www.smaizys.com/php/mpdf-html-to-pdf-introduction/)
[Tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
[pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)
[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

I personally recommend `wkhtmltopdf`. It uses the [WebKit](http://www.webkit.org/%5C) engine and then generates PDF files. If you use it, you should also not have to change much of your app since this 
two is a executable file that you'll have to call whit exec() (if on Linux/Unix) or [COM Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) if on (Windows).